# Cómo mejorar la organización de una clase que implementa múltiples repositorios en Spring Boot

Tags: java, regex, spring, repository

En un proyecto personal con Spring Boot 2.3.10 y Java 8, me acabo de topar con esta situación, y quiero conocer cuál es la mejor forma de afrontar el caso.

Tengo un servicio que utiliza 20 repositorios distintos, con sus entidades y métodos distintos. La clase en sí no tiene demasiadas líneas (400 aprox.) pero me interesa el mejorar la inyección de dependencias de la clase.

Adjunto una breve parte del código para no ser tan extenso.

```
    @Autowired
    private RegionRepository regionRepository;
    @Autowired
    private RegimenRepository regimenRepository;
    @Autowired
    private FormaDePagoRepository formaDePagoRepository;
    @Autowired
    private SegmentoRepository segmentoRepository;
    @Autowired
    private FormaDeIngresoRepository formaDeIngresoRepository;
```

¿Alguien tiene alguna sugerencia?

He pensado en utilizar el patrón facade, y de quitar el autowired y directamente trabajarlo sobre el constructor, pero no estoy seguro de que sería la mejor opción.

¿Qué otras opciones podría considerar?

Gracias

Answer (score -1):

De hecho lo más recomendable es trabajar con las inyecciones desde el constructor, más que nada por las pruebas unitarias:

```
private final RegionRepository regionRepository;
private final RegimenRepository regimenRepository;
private final FormaDePagoRepository formaDePagoRepository;
private final SegmentoRepository segmentoRepository;
private final FormaDeIngresoRepository formaDeIngresoRepository;

@Autowired
public TuService(RegionRepository regionRepository, RegimenRepository regimenRepository, FormaDePagoRepository formaDePagoRepository, SegmentoRepository segmentoRepository, FormaDeIngresoRepository formaDeIngresoRepository) {
    this.regionRepository = regionRepository;
    this.regimenRepository = regimenRepository;
    this.formaDePagoRepository = formaDePagoRepository;
    this.segmentoRepository = segmentoRepository;
    this.formaDeIngresoRepository = formaDeIngresoRepository;
}
```

Comment: Gracias @setodimario, pero no crees que al tener 20 inyecciones, el constructor quedaria mounstruosamente grande? Por esto era que preguntaba si el patron facade podia solucionar mi problema, sin generar un nuevo problema